# Regex at least One Uppercase, One Lowercase, One Digit, and optionally allow any other character, min length of 8 and max length of 72

Tags: c#, regex

I have the Regex below.

This matches if there is:

- At least one uppercase
- At least one lowercase
- At least one digit
- At least one non-alphanumerical

How can I make the non-alphanumerical optional?

`^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[^a-zA-Z\d]).{8,72}$`

Would something like this be ok?

`^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.?[a-zA-Z\d]).{8,72}$`

Comment: Regex is a really heavy-handed tool for something like this. You spent how much time writing a complicated regex expression, admitted failure, wrote a question, and waited how long?  In far less time, you could've written a method to loop through the characters, classify each one and set a flag, and assert that all flags are set and that the length is within the limits.

Comment: As for your question at the end: `^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.?[a-zA-Z\d]).{8,72}$` wouldn't work: `(?=.?[a-zA-Z\d])` is the 4th lookahead assertion after the beginning `^` of the string. At that point, `.?` would match any single optional character (still at the beginning of the string), while `[a-zA-Z\d]` would require exactly 1 alphanumeric character. That is, this 4th lookahead assertion checks *whether the 1st or 2nd character of the string is alphanumeric*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply omit the *positive lookahead assertion* (`?=`) for the non-alphanumeric part:

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d).{8,72}$
```

(Making a condition – here: "at least 1 non-alphanumeric character" – optional is equivalent to not having such a restriction at all.)

By the way, I noticed you using `\d`. This is not wrong, but most people write `[A-Za-z0-9]` instead of `[A-Za-z\d]`. If the regular expression settings are such that all Unicode characters are considered, `\d` potentially matches much more than just the 10 digits `[0-9]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a regex that includes all of the Unicode 149,186 valid characters (V15)
as a constraint `[^\p{Cn}\p{Cc}\p{Cs}\p{Co}]*`.
Then add other Unicode constraints `\p{Lu}, \p{Ll}, \p{Nd}` that are required.
Then finally add the *Block* of characters Unicode constraint.
This can be any block: `\p{Latin}, \p{Greek}, \p{Hebrew}`, etc...,
or even a range of characters `[\udddd-\udddd]`.

Regex engines nowadays have entirely different meaning of dot-all `.`.

```
^(?=[\x21-\x7e]{8,72}$)(?=.*\p{Lu})(?=.*\p{Ll})(?=.*\p{Nd})[^\p{Cn}\p{Cc}\p{Cs}\p{Co}]*$
```

https://regex101.com/r/V8FxMV/1

```
 ^ 
 (?= [\x21-\x7e]{8,72} $ )
 (?= .* \p{Lu} )
 (?= .* \p{Ll} )
 (?= .* \p{Nd} )
 [^\p{Cn}\p{Cc}\p{Cs}\p{Co}]* 
 $
```